# Retirar a borda de uma imagem ao ser clicada

Tags: css, html5

Estou tendo problema com um menu que tem imagens com redirecionamento para `modal`, quando fecho o `modal` ele fica com uma borda azul no Chrome e pontilhada no IE, já tentei `outline: none` e `border: 0`.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Quero retirar desta imagem:

```
<a href="#Concursos" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Concursos" class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center home">
<img src="icones/icone_Concursos.png" alt="Concursos" /></a>

 .centro_site {
width: 100%; float: left; padding: 0px 10px; margin-top: 10px; outline: none;
}
```

E ela ainda esta dentro no `.row` do `bootscrap`, mais já coloquei tudo 0 também os `outline` do `bootscrap`.

Comment: Adicione o CSS para podermos ajudá-lo, e onde você adicionou o `outline:none` que não funcionou, pois deveria...

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: As imagens estão com a class .home. Adicionei la também e não deu certo .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Achei o problema. Eu uso bootscrap e estava dentro de uma `div .row` e como eu uso menu de colunas ficava circulando os links da imagens. Os `outline` estam definidos como `5px` dentro do `a.focus` do bootscrap.css e bootscrap.min.css.

Answer (score 1):

Simples, o outline não é da imagem e sim do link que circunda ela, o código abaixo resolve o seu problema;

```
a:active, a:selected, a:visited { 
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Amigo. Postei minha solução. Achei o problema. Eu uso bootscrap e os links estavam dentro da row do bootscrap. Os outline estavam definidos como 5px nos arquivos do bootscrap. Mais valeu. Obrigado pela resposta. Vendo talvez resolveria mesmo. Eu tinha tentado esse metodo aí somente com a:active e também não tinha dado certo. Mais valeu.